# Allow SVG graphics to overflow outside the containing svg element

Tags: css, svg, overflow

I'm using the Raphaël—JavaScript Library to create some pie chart graphics, but I want to set the overflow of the containing SVG element to visible, to allow the graphics inside to display outside of their container. The way you would with normal dom elements (overflow: visible;) does not seem to work for svg containers.
Does anyone have any experience of this or know how to remedy it?

Cheers

Comment: Why not just change the size of the container to prevent the clipping?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hacking the layout, making the container bigger and positioning it would ruin the flow for the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378923).

WebKit implements `overflow: visible` correctly for SVG elements, as does IE for VML elements.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else stumbling upon this old answer from Google - the `overflow: visible` now works as expected in Firefox.

Comment: Does not works for me. I use `<div style='width:100%;'>
  <img src='/svg/gcchart.php' style='height:425px;overflow-x:scroll; direction:rtl;' />
 </div>` and somehow this image can't overflow. The same result goes for `overflow-x:visible`. In the SVG I use width, weight and viewbox attributes. EDIT: It works after replacing img with embed.